# Put angular and laravel under the same root folder (.htaccess)

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, angular, angular-routing

I have this folder structure

```
--laravel
----public
------index.php
------uploads
--------image.jpg
--angular
----dist
------index.html
```

I want 3 things

1) http(s)://www.domain.com/public/uploads/image.jpg goes to laravel->public->uploads->image.jpg

2) http(s)://www.domain.com/api/test goes to laravel->public->index.php

3) http(s)://www.domain.com/every_other_url goes to angular->dist

I have create this .htacces file

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm default.htm index.php index.php3 index.phtml index.php5 index.shtml mwindex.phtml
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ laravel/public/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ laravel/public/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/angular/dist/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /angular/dist/$1
</IfModule>
```

First and second requirements works properly. Now I need to fix the 3rd

(I'm not using the HashLocationStrategy)

Answer (score 2):

```
DirectoryIndex /angular/dist/index.html    
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ laravel/public/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ laravel/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(.*) /angular/dist/$1.$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /angular/dist/index.html [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ laravel/public/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ laravel/public/$1 [L]

Above rules are not working. It is redirecting to angular route strategy instead of laravel